# Staying for one night in Montréal

Tags: budget, montreal

I'm going to stay one night in Montréal (from 23/08 to 24/08) with my girlfriend.

I know that "what's the cheapest..." questions are not on-topic here, so I'm not going to ask about a particular place.

Is there a cheaper alternative to hotel? Also, what would you recommend regarding jet lag? I'm going to arrive by air around 4 PM, and the 24 will be a tough day for me (around 6 hours of jet lag).

Comment: The jetlag question should be separate but assuming you are coming from Europe, don't worry too much about it, you will simply have a slightly longer day than usual and sleep easily. The trip in the other direction is probably going to be tougher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hostels (google them) are usually cheaper than hotels but you have to be wanting to be with other people.

Bed&Breakfast could is another suggestion (but usually not cheaper).

Try university lodging; they sometimes rent out student apartments in the summer (but at the time you will be here it will be probably be over).

For example, Université de Montreal: http://www.studioshotel.ca/

If really cheap, you could "couch surf" at someone's apartment (I don't approve it, so look for it yourself).

Comment: Hostels are what I was looking for (It seems so at least!). Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget AirBnB.

Comment: If you have transport (car) you could look into motels out of town. I stayed near Trois Rivieres, with my boyfriend, for the cost of to in a hostel in the city.

Comment: If you want a motel, no need to travel 1h30 to Trois Rivière!!!